# Audio doesn't work in a Samsung Galaxy A32 5G running Android 12 on an app compiled through Cordova

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, audio, playcanvas

When I launch the game on Samsung Galaxy A32 5G running Android 12 the audio can't be heard.

Platforms on which I've confirmed the audio **functions as intended**:

> - Windows 11 on Chrome, Firefox, and compiled into a UWP with Cordova
> - Windows 10 on Chrome, Firefox, and compiled into a UWP with Cordova
> - MacOS 12 Monterey on Chrome and Safari
> - iPad Air 2 (IOS v15.6.1) on Safari
> - Google Pixel 2 on Chrome
> - Samsung Galaxy A10e running Android 11 on Chrome, Samsung Internet, and compiled into an APK with Cordova.
> - Another individual told me it worked on their Samsung Galaxy A32 5G running Android 12 through their browser.
> - My My personal 2 identical Samsung Galaxy A32 5Gs running Android 12 on Samsung Internet

Platforms on which the audio **does not function as intended**:

> - My personal 2 identical Samsung Galaxy A32 5Gs running Android 12 on Chrome and compiled into an APK with Cordova.

I have tried switching the audio file format from MPEG-3 to Ogg Vorbis and this did not fix the issue.

I did have an ounce of success though... I have a pair of Bluetooth headphones and I decided to connect them to see if it made a difference. When I connected them with the program already open the sound didn’t work but if I restarted the application with them connected then the audio would work. Then if I disconnected my headphones in the middle of the audio working the audio would continue working until I restarted the application at which time it would revert to its broken state.

**Here is a fork of Flappy Bird which replicates the issue: https://playcanvas.com/project/976119/overview/flappy-bird**

Comment: Hi Josh, exact same problem here. I'm working on a musical JS/Cordova app targeting both iOS and Android. I encountered the same problem, no sounds at all on the Samsung A32 5G when using AudioContext (our users are confirming the problem). Your trick with the bluetooth works the same as yours from my side. Did you find any solution? For now we had no other choices than excluding SA32 from our Google Play developper console (which is not great because it's a very common device model). Thanks

Comment: Just for info: I tried upgrading the Android version on the Samsung A32 5G and it doesn't fix anything... Android 11 -> no sound / Android 12 -> no sound / Android 13 -> no sound...